SysTick clock frequency on QEMU
I am experimenting on ARM M3 cortex using QEMU for stm32vldiscovery.
My code looks like below
// Vector table
.section .vectors
.word 0x20000800          // Stack pointer value
.word reset_handler       // Reset handler
.word 0                  // NMI handler
.word 0                  // Hard fault handler
.word 0                  // Memory management fault
.word 0                  // Bus fault
.word 0                  // Usage fault
.word 0                  // Reserved
.word 0                  // Reserved
.word 0                  // Reserved
.word 0                  // Reserved
.word 0                  // SVCall
.word 0                  // Debug monitor
.word 0                  // Reserved
.word 0                  // PendSV
.word systick_handler // SysTick handler
.zero 4

.section .text
.align 2                 // Align to 4 bytes
.thumb                   // Use Thumb instruction set
.global reset_handler
.type reset_handler, %function

reset_handler:
   // Jump to main
    b main

#include <stdint.h>

// SysTick registers
#define SYSTICK_BASE    0xE000E010
#define SYSTICK_CTRL    *((volatile uint32_t *)(SYSTICK_BASE + 0x00))
#define SYSTICK_LOAD    *((volatile uint32_t *)(SYSTICK_BASE + 0x04))
#define SYSTICK_VAL     *((volatile uint32_t *)(SYSTICK_BASE + 0x08))
#define NVIC_ISER0      *((volatile uint32_t *)0xE000E100)

// Control register bits
#define SYSTICK_ENABLE  (1 << 0)
#define SYSTICK_TICKINT (1 << 1)
#define SYSTICK_CLKSRC  (1 << 2)

// Global variable to verify interrupt is working
volatile uint32_t tick_count = 0;

static void systick_enable(void) {
    // Set reload value (adjust based on your clock frequency)
    SYSTICK_LOAD = 300 - 1;

    // Enable SysTick interrupt in NVIC
    NVIC_ISER0 |= (1 << 15);

    // Enable SysTick with interrupt and internal clock source
    SYSTICK_CTRL = SYSTICK_ENABLE | SYSTICK_TICKINT | SYSTICK_CLKSRC;
}

int main(void) {
    systick_enable();

    while(1) {
        // Main loop
        // You can check tick_count here to verify interrupt is working
        //tick_count += 1;
    }
}

void systick_handler(void) {
    tick_count++;  // Increment global counter
}

Now when I run this via QEMU and connect gdb , I am able to see tick_count value change.
However, I want to know the exact clock fed to Systick.
Since I set bit2 in CTRL register, I use SYSCLK which as per the document is "After a system reset, the HSI oscillator is selected as system clock == 8 MHz"
I went to check RCC_CR register whose default value is 0x83 after reset,but I see 0 when I do
>>> x 0x40021000
Any idea how I can find the clock value ?

its emulated, I would not expect any kind of reality with respect to timers.
